# How do I page.click an ember.js computed element?

Tags: puppeteer, cucumberjs

I have an ember.js front end app that I'm trying to create an E2E test using cucumber.js / puppeteer.  I'm using html data- properties for selectors.  I'm having a problem when I have a computed element:

```
<p class="ao-label" data-test-upload1="true">Drag and Drop Files or 
    {{#file-upload 
        name="transactions"
        class="ao-file-uploader__file"
        multiple=false
        onfileadd=(action "validateFile")
        accept=allowFileTypeString 
        data-test-upload2="true"
    }}
<a class="ao-button ao-button--link" data-test-upload3="true">Click to Browse</a>
```

and I attempt to `page.click` it:

```
async selectLinkToImportPaymentFile() {
    await this.page.click('[test-selector-upload1="true"]');
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: No node found for selector: [test-selector-upload1="true"]

I tried `test-selector-upload1`, `test-selector-upload2`, and `test-selector-upload3`.

I can do it on other elements, such as this one (I can `page.click`):

```
<button class="ao-login__button" data-test-selector="buttonSignIn" type="submit">
    Sign in
</button>
```

Can someone please give me some guidance?

Comment: I may be missing something about Cucumber, but where is the element in the snippet you showed that has a `test-selector-upload1` attribute whose value is `true`?

Comment: I figured it out - needed a time delay to render.

Comment: Glad you found the solution! If you could write it up as an answer and accept it, that’ll also help anyone who stumbles on this question in future.